# Dynamically creating Django models with `type`

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, metaclass

I have 20+ MySQL tables, `prm_a`, `prm_b`, ... with the same basic structure but different names, and I'd like to associate them with Django model classes without writing each one by hand. So, feeling ambitious, I thought I'd try my hand at using `type()` as a class-factory:

The following works:

```
def get_model_meta_class(prm_name):
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'myapp'
    setattr(Meta, 'db_table', 'prm_%s' % prm_name)
    return Meta

prm_class_attrs = {
    'foo': models.ForeignKey(Foo),
    'val': models.FloatField(),
    'err': models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True),
    'source': models.ForeignKey(Source),
    '__module__': __name__,
}

###
prm_a_attrs = prm_class_attrs.copy()
prm_a_attrs['Meta'] = get_model_meta_class('a')
Prm_a = type('Prm_a', (models.Model,), prm_a_attrs)

prm_b_attrs = prm_class_attrs.copy()
prm_b_attrs['Meta'] = get_model_meta_class('b')
Prm_b = type('Prm_b', (models.Model,), prm_b_attrs)
###
```

But if I try to generate the model classes as follows:

```
###
prms = ['a', 'b']
for prm_name in prms:
    prm_class_name = 'Prm_%s' % prm_name
    prm_class = type(prm_class_name, (models.Model,), prm_class_attrs)
    setattr(prm_class, 'Meta', get_model_meta_class(prm_name))
    globals()[prm_class_name] = prm_class
###
```

I get a curious Exception on the `type()` line (given that `__module__` is, in fact, in the `prm_class_attrs` dictionary):

```
File ".../models.py", line 168, in <module>
    prm_class = type(prm_class_name, (models.Model,), prm_class_attrs)
  File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 79, in __new__
    module = attrs.pop('__module__')
KeyError: u'__module__'
```

So I have two questions: what's wrong with my second approach, and is this even the right way to go about creating my class models?

OK - thanks to @Anentropic, I see that the items in my `prm_class_attrs` dictionary are being popped away by Python when it makes the classes. And I now have it working, but only if I do this:

```
attrs = prm_class_attrs.copy()
attrs['Meta'] = get_model_meta_class(prm_name)
prm_class = type(prm_class_name, (models.Model,), attrs)
```

not if I set the `Meta` class as an attribtue with

```
setattr(prm_class, 'Meta', get_model_meta_class(prm_name))
```

I don't really know why this is, but at least I have it working now.

Comment: because you are not doing `prm_class_attrs.copy()` in your `for` loop so `__modules__` is getting popped out of the dict in the first iteration

Comment: I had no idea you had to provide `__module__`!  This question was really helpful!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The imediate reason is because you are not doing `prm_class_attrs.copy()` in your `for` loop, so the `__modules__` key is getting popped out of the dict on the first iteration

As for why this doesn't work:

`setattr(prm_class, 'Meta', get_model_meta_class(prm_name))`

...it's to do with the fact that Django's `models.Model` has a metaclass. But this is a *[Python metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6581949/202168)* which customises the creation of the model class and is nothing to do with the `Meta` inner-class of the Django model (which just provides 'meta' information about the model).

In fact, despite how it looks when you define the class in your `models.py`, the resulting class does not have a `Meta` attribute:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'WTF'

>>> MyModel.Meta
AttributeError: type object 'MyModel' has no attribute 'Meta'
```

(You *can* access the `Meta` class directly, but aliased as `MyModel._meta`)

The model you define in `models.py` is really more of a template for a model class than the actual model class. This is why when you access a field attribute on a model instance you get the *value* of that field, not the field object itself.

Django [model inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance) can simplify a bit what you're doing:

```
class GeneratedModelBase(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        app_label = 'myapp'

    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
    val = models.FloatField()
    err = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    source = models.ForeignKey(Source)

def generate_model(suffix):
    prm_class_name = 'Prm_%s' % prm_name
    prm_class = type(
        prm_class_name,
        (GeneratedModelBase,),
        {
            # this will get merged with the attrs from GeneratedModelBase.Meta
            'Meta': {'db_table', 'prm_%s' % prm_name},
            '__module__': __name__,
        }
    )
    globals()[prm_class_name] = prm_class
    return prm_class

prms = ['a', 'b']
for prm_name in prms:
    generate_model(prm_name)
```

Comment: I've been looking all over for a concise concrete example of how to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `./manage.py inspectdb` 
This will print out a python models file for the DB you're pointing at in your `settings.py`
[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb)

**EDIT**
For dynamic models, try [django-mutant](https://github.com/charettes/django-mutant) or check out [this link](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels)

Comment: I see that this would work if the database were static and fixed, but if I want to add a table, I'd like the code to generate the corresponding model on the fly.

Comment: @xnx you're going to have to write a bunch of other code to use the table in your app though surely?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still wondering how to do this, I took the genius answer from @Anentropic and made it work with some modifications.

I also changed the db table name to something more like django uses to name the tables of the models ("appname_lowercaseclassname") by stripping all non alphabetic characters from the class name and converting the resulting string to lower case.

I Tested it on Django 2.2.6

```
def generate_model(class_name):

    clean_name_for_table = ''.join(filter(str.isalpha, class_name)).lower() # Could also use regex to remove all non alphabetic characters.
    db_table_name = f"{__package__}_{clean_name_for_table}"
    prm_class = type(
        class_name,
        (BaseClass,),
        {
            # this will get merged with the attrs from GeneratedModelBase.Meta
            'Meta': type("Meta",(),{'db_table':db_table_name}),
            '__module__': __name__,
        }
    )
    globals()[class_name] = prm_class
    return prm_class
```